# Error: Template must have exactly one root element when creating a custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to make a simple directive that has a button that will show if the cursor is placed over it. However, every time I include this new directive into my index.html I receive this error in return.

Here is the following error:

[Error shown on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB0lC.png)

Here is my template code:

```
<div>
    <button ng-show="ishovering">DELETE</button>
</div>
```

Here is my directive code:

```
app.directive('deleteArea',function(){
return {
    scope: {},
    require: 'ng-show', 
    restrict: "AE",
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: "./templates/delete.html",
    link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
        elem.bind('mouseover',function(){
            elem.css('cursor','pointer');
            scope.$apply(function(){
                scope.ishovering = true;
            });
        });
    }
};
});
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: how are you including that directive ?

Comment: I have it included in one of the divs in my index.html simply as <delete-area/>

Comment: The problem resides with some other code, the code given by you will throw compile error as there is no directive named 'ng-show', and that you are using in your `require` statement.

Comment: Second thing the button in your directive will never show as the `scope.ishovering` will always have `falsy` value.

Answer (score 0):

Just use bootstrap for angular called [ui.bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) .
Use the popover directive that will give you the effect you need.